# Efficiently Classify Coordinates by Rectangular Zones of Different Sizes

Tags: python, pandas, classification, coordinates

I have a set of coordinates that I want to classify by whether they are in one of several rectangular zones, which have different sizes. Here is an example of what they look like.

[image]

And here are some of the coordinates I would want to classify:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| -2210 | -3 |
| -2220 | 8 |
| -2215 | 0 |

Each zone is defined in a dataframe called "zone_df" by its top-left XY position and bottom right XY position.

| ZonesDesignation | XCoordTopLeft | YCoordTopLeft | XCoordBotRight | YCoordBotRight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -2225 | -11 | -2208 | -2 |
| 2 | -2225 | -1 | -2208 | 6 |
| 3 | -2225 | 7 | -2216 | 13 |

My current way of doing this is probably not at all efficient and pretty buggy:

```
def get_zone_by_coordinates(zone_df,x,y):
  result = zone_df.loc[(zone_df.XCoordTopLeft < x) & ((zone_df.XCoordBotRight) >= x) 
    & ((zone_df.YCoordTopLeft) < y) & ((zone_df.YCoordBotRight) >= y)]['ZonesDesignation'].values
  if len(result)== 1:
    return result[0]
  else:
    return 0
```

Using Pandas, I iterate through each row of the dataframe of coordinates and apply this function, returning the result. But is this really the best I can hope for?

Comment: Can you provide a test dataframe (as text)?

Comment: @mozway just added them! Let me know if anything else is needed.